# Ionic infinite scroll with collection repeat - scrollbar jumping back to middle issue

Tags: ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

Having a infinite scroll (with new items loaded by remote calls) together with collection repeat and items of different size, I have an issue that after new batch of item is renedered, the scrollbar "jumps" to the middle, or to explain it other way around, it is not on the bottom where it should be (on the button but moved a bit back to accomodate for the new items).

Comment: Altough this is a self-answered question which I hope will help somebody else in the future, other tips /answers in stack overflow spirit are always good

Answer (score 3):

The most probable issue is that

> this.$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

is called **BEFORE** the items are added to the array / rendered.

One easy way to do this is if items are added as a result of a promise, but $broadcast is done before the promise is completed.

Answer (score 0):

solved this by setting `item-render-buffer` property of `collection-repeat`

```
<div collection-repeat="business in businesses" item-height="120px" item-render-buffer="10"></div>
```